# Equation with summation symbol in numerator and denominator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I am having some difficulty understanding the following formula (primarily because of presence of a summation symbol in the denominator):$$A = \frac{ \sum_{i=0}^1 (x_i+1) \times P_i} {\sum_{i=0}^1 P_i}$$

Here is my interpretation of what the formula means:$$A = \frac {((x_0+1)\times P_0)}{P_0}  + \frac{((x_1+1)\times P_1)}{P_1}$$

Am I getting this right ? Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nope**, what you have is incorrect.
$$\dfrac{\sum_{i=0}^1 (x_i+1)P_i}{\sum_{i=0}^1 P_i} = \dfrac{(x_0+1)P_0 + (x_1 + 1)P_1}{P_0 + P_1}$$
The above is the correct interpretation. What you have written is
$$\dfrac{((x_0+1)\times P_0)}{P_0}  + \dfrac{((x_1+1)\times P_1)}{P_1}$$ which is
$$\sum_{i=0}^1 \dfrac{(x_i+1)P_i}{P_i}$$

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 2):

No this is not right. You treat the numerator and the denominator independently. A is one fraction, not a sum of fractions as you have written. What you have written would be the case if it were $\sum_{i=0}^1 \frac{(x_i+1)P_i}{P_i}$.